# jQuery - index is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do something like: if the URL contains "type=department" do something.

I have the following code:

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
if(url.index("type=department") >= 0){
    do something
}
```

But my console writes me: **Uncaught TypeError: url.index is not a function**

What is wrong?

Comment: The correct method is `indexOf()`. Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: Just for completeness, as it's possibly the source of your confusion; jQuery has an [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function as `index()`, You need [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if(url.indexOf("type=department") >= 0){
   //Do something
}
```

You can also use [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

```
if(url.includes("type=department")){
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: I had indexOf there before and it wrote me that indexOf is not function of jquery.

Comment: @MichalVlasák, `index()` is a jQuery method where as `indexOf()` is native string method

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking when you say the URL you mean your browser url...  If so, then what you should do is this.

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

So what you will do with that function is below...

lets say your url is http://www.example.com?type=department, you would do the following ...

```
var type = getUrlParameter('department');
if(type!=undefined){
    do something here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, [look it up in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> `.attr( attributeName )` Returns: [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)

And since the return type is a good old JavaScript string rather than a jQuery object you can use [standard JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) where we can see no trace of any `index()` method. However, we see several methods to find substrings, such as [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> Strings are useful for holding data that can be represented in text
>   form. Some of the most-used operations on strings are to check their
>   length, to build and concatenate them using the + and += string
>   operators, **checking for the existence or location of substrings with
>   the indexOf() method**, or extracting substrings with the substring()
>   method.